# What is difference between inportb() and inport() function?

Tags: c++, c, dos

I've newly started learning `System Programming`. I got confused with these two functions. could any one tell me what are the differences between these Functions

`inportb()` and `inport()`

`outportb()` and `outport()`
 ??

Comment: The ones with a b are 8 bit inputs, the ones without the b are 16 bit inputs.

Comment: C has neither of those functions. I'd say one handles one byte and the other > 1.

Comment: See this: http://stilzchen.kfunigraz.ac.at/skripten/comput/kapitel2/schnittstellen/parallel/doc/data/bc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inportb()` and `outportb()` are macros. Plus, `outportb()` accepts an `int port` and a `char byte` whereas `outport()` has `int port` and `int word` as parameters.

Please see [this link](http://members.tripod.com/vitaly_filatov/ng/tc/tc_000.148.html) for some more details.